# removing a view controller on click of a button

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I am developing a library for a iOS app that will authenticate the users on the basis of the credential entered by them.

What I am doing is that, from a view controller say `TestViewController` I am setting a new view controller `LoginScreenViewController` on top of `TestViewController` when user taps a button by using the following code.

```
LoginScreenViewController * LoginScreen = [[LoginScreenViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

[self.view addSubview:LoginScreen.view];
```

This `LoginScreenViewController` contains a `Cancel` button, on which I want to remove the `LoginScreenViewController`. For this I am using following code

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

the problem is when I am executing this code, my app is crashing.

Since my `LoginScreenViewController` is defined by the Library, I want it to be independent of the caller's implementation.

**EDIT**:
In `LoginScreenViewController.m` I have used following code to add an event handler to the cancel button.

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(CancelButtonHandler:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

The app is crashing when I am tapping the `Cancel` button. Even if the `CancelButtonHandler` does not contain any line of code.

Comment: can you tell what error you getting? and also make sure that self.view is not nil in [self.view removeFromSuperview];

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to remove wrong view. To remove LoginScreen view do:

```
[LoginScreen.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: the event to handle the functionality of `Cancel` button has to be defined in `LoginScreenViewController`. So there I can use `self.view` only.

Comment: But i guess your self is still pointing to TestViewController , not to the LoginScreenViewController, try to push LoginScreenViewController instead adding as a subview.

Comment: for pushing a view controller, i need to know that the library user is using a `NavigationController`. Only then I will be able to push by `LoginScreenViewController`. Am I correct ?

Comment: you can easily keep reference in property for LoginScreenViewController in your class to use it later - really basics.